# How to set the File Info

Tags: c#

I am writing this below code in my C# project. I am getting the following error:

The best overloaded method match for `System.IO.File.FileInfo` has some invalid arguments;

Whether the code is correct or not.

```
FileInfo file = new FileInfo(ViewState["value"]);
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

My guess is that you just need to cast to string:

```
FileInfo file = new FileInfo((string) ViewState["value"]);
```

Basically `ViewState[string]` returns an object, and there's no `FileInfo(object)` constructor - that's what the compiler was complaining about.

Answer (score 1):

You could do

```
FileInfo file = new FileInfo(ViewState["value"].ToString());
```